# Automatic iOS update does not work on iPhone XS

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I have an iPhone XS running iOS 13.3.1. I have just had the following screen:

[image]

Nothing new here. My problem is that it doesn't work. I have been doing this repeatedly for the past week. In fact, I can't remember the last time my iPhone successfully updated overnight. I don't get any error messages, no "Update Failed" or anything, I just wake up the next day and my phone hasn't updated. And at some point I'll see the above screen again.

My phone is sitting on a wireless charger and I am connected to wifi. The version I am trying to update to is 13.4.1. I can see no reason for it not to update.

Obviously I can update manually, but I would much prefer to get this working. How can I find out what is going wrong? Are there any logs anywhere I can look at?

**UPDATE:**

After a week of trying, this has finally updated overnight, although I have no idea what, if anything, I did differently this time, so would still like to know why it didn't update before.

Comment: iOS 13.4.1 is the latest current public release of iOS.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Hi, apologies. I was reading the version from the Software Update page (so that's the version I was trying to update to). I am actually on 13.3.1. I'll update the question.